# Exibir mensagem

Tags: python-3.x

```
compras = []
valores=[]

def pede_produto():
    return (input("Produto: "))

def pede_preco():
    return float(input("Preço: "))

def mostra_dados(produto, preco):
    print('\nProduto \nNome: {} \nPreço: {}' .format(produto, preco))


def novo():

    quantidade = int(input('Quantos produtos que comprar? '))
    for x in range(quantidade):
        print('Produto e Preço', x + 1)
        produto = pede_produto()
        preco = pede_preco()
        compras.append([produto, preco])
        valores.append(preco)


def lista():

        print("\nCompras\n\n------")
        print('Quantidade: {}'.format(len(compras)))
        print('total',sum(valores))
        for e in compras:
            mostra_dados(e[0], e[1])




def valida_faixa_inteiro(pergunta, inicio, fim):
    while True:
        try:
            valor = int(input(pergunta))
            if inicio <= valor <= fim:
                return (valor)
        except ValueError:
            print("Valor inválido, favor digitar entre %d e %d" % (inicio, fim))


def menu():
    print("""
   1 - Novo
   2 - Lista
   0 - Sai
""")
    return valida_faixa_inteiro("Escolha uma opção: ", 0, 3)


while True:
    opção = menu()
    if opção == 0:
        break
    elif opção == 1:
        novo()

    elif opção == 2:
        lista()
```

Como faço  colocar mesnagem (produto nao cadatrado) em def lista() caso o produto nao for cadastrado e exibir esse formato de saída

```
Produto 1:
nome:
preço:
Produto 2:
nome:
Preço:
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Rafael,

Para colocar a mensagem *'produto não cadastrado'* caso a lista esteja vazia, você pode criar uma condição na função `lista` que verifica a lista (`compras`) antes de efetuar o loop de impressão, usando por exemplo o `not`:

```
if not compras:
  print("\nProduto não cadastrado")
```

Já para efetuar a saída na formatação que você deseja, seu código parece já estar bem próximo, faltando apenas enumerar os produtos, para ter acesso ao índice dos produtos, você pode utilizar da função [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), utilizando ela em seu for, tendo acesso assim ao produto e também ao índice da lista:

```
for i, e in enumerate(compras):
```

Sendo a que a primeira posição no for é o índice e a segunda é o elemento da lista.

Com isso você pode alterar a sua função `mostra_dados` para exibir o número do produto:

```
def mostra_dados(produto, preco, numero):
  print('\nProduto: {}\nNome: {} \nPreço: {}' .format(numero, produto, preco))
```

Lembrando que o índice em Python começa em zero, antes de enviar o valor para a função `mostra_dados`, soma-se um ao valor do índice:

```
mostra_dados(e[0], e[1], i + 1)
```

---

Agora é juntar tudo, tendo um resultado mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
compras = []
valores=[]

def pede_produto():
  return (input("Produto: "))

def pede_preco():
  return float(input("Preço: "))

def mostra_dados(produto, preco, numero):
  print('\nProduto: {}\nNome: {} \nPreço: {}' .format(numero, produto, preco))


def novo():
  quantidade = int(input('Quantos produtos que comprar? '))

  for x in range(quantidade):
    print('Produto e Preço', x + 1)
    produto = pede_produto()
    preco = pede_preco()
    compras.append([produto, preco])
    valores.append(preco)


def lista():
  if not compras:
    print("\nProduto não cadastrado")
  else:
    print("\nCompras\n\n------")
    print('Quantidade: {}'.format(len(compras)))
    print('Total',sum(valores))

    for i, e in enumerate(compras):
      mostra_dados(e[0], e[1], i + 1)


def valida_faixa_inteiro(pergunta, inicio, fim):
  while True:
    try:
      valor = int(input(pergunta))
      if inicio <= valor <= fim:
        return (valor)
    except ValueError:
      print("Valor inválido, favor digitar entre %d e %d" % (inicio, fim))


def menu():
  print("""
   1 - Novo
   2 - Lista
   0 - Sai
""")
  return valida_faixa_inteiro("Escolha uma opção: ", 0, 3)


while True:
  opção = menu()

  if opção == 0:
    break
  elif opção == 1:
    novo()
  elif opção == 2:
    lista()
```

---

> Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/GlassZigzagProfiler

Comment: Obrigado Daniel e Luiz